# How do I make my game load faster and more functions?

Tags: python, performance

So far, I have made a game with turtle. There will be two turtles on the left and side and the right hand side at the start of the game.

Then, two players have to use `wasd` and up down left right keys to control the snake. I want to make my game load faster (now, when I press up and right quickly, my game wouldn't be able to load. I have to press then slower for it to be able to load. is there a way for it to load faster?) Also, the end of my snake will just stay at the place where it started. Is there a way for the end of the snake to move along the head? for example, make the length 10. (examples can be seen on powerline.io)

Here is my code:

```
#imports
from turtle import Screen
import turtle
import asyncio

#set up screen
wn = Screen()

#define speed
speeda = 1
speedb = 1

#set up the snakes
a = turtle.Turtle()
a.color("red")
a.up()
a.backward(250)
a.right(90)
a.forward(140)
a.left(180)
a.down()

b = turtle.Turtle()
b.color("blue")
b.up()
b.forward(250)
b.right(90)
b.forward(140)
b.left(180)
b.down()

#a keys
def up():
  if a.heading() != 270:
    a.setheading(90)
def down():
  if a.heading() != 90:
    a.setheading(270)
def left():
  if a.heading() != 0:
    a.setheading(180)
def right():
  if a.heading() != 180:
    a.setheading(0)
  
#b keys
def u():
  if b.heading() != 270:
    b.setheading(90)
def d():
  if b.heading() != 90:
    b.setheading(270)
def l():
  if b.heading() != 0:
    b.setheading(180)
def r():
  if b.heading() != 180:
    b.setheading(0)

wn.listen()
wn.onkey(up, 'w')
wn.onkey(down, 's')
wn.onkey(left, 'a')
wn.onkey(right, 'd')
wn.onkey(u, 'Up')
wn.onkey(d, 'Down')
wn.onkey(l, 'Left')
wn.onkey(r, 'Right')

while True:
  a.forward(speeda)
  b.forward(speedb)
```

Any help shall be appreciated!

Comment: your game is basically an infinite loop that advances the turtles forward. By the time you manage to press a key the position of the turtles will be thousands of units forward

Comment: so what can i do about it?

Comment: Decrease speed, and/or make some delay in the loop. But best what you could do is find some tutorial/course that will help you through, step by step create simple game/application.